How to train Logistic regression model with multiple inputs for 1 target value?
My data looks like similar to this: (the picture below is not mine, but describes perfectly my situation)

where the IDs are not unique but for each ID value I have a unique target value The following solution has been suggested:

But sadly that solution does not work with me (I do not have only one table that has duplicate IDs), is there any other way to solve this problem?
PS: I do not whether I should credit from where I took the picture or something like that,just mention it in the comments and I will do it, Thank you.

If I understand you correctly, you have duplicate Ys for some of the observations.  Though not optimal, a simple way to handle this with a tall and thin dataset is to estimate (we don’t say “train” in statistical modeling) coefficients of the model the usual way, then to use the Huber-White cluster sandwich covariance estimator to increase the standard errors to reflect the duplications.  For example you can use the R rms package robcov function.
But looking back at your question I’m confused at why you mentioned logistic regression (and which one?  Binary?  Ordinal?) and I think you have multiple targets per observations, which I may or may not be reasonable to put into a super tall and thin data arrangement.
